# Windows 10 1511 Windows Updates - view available updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm using Windows 10 1511.

I can't find anywhere in the new Windows Update UI to get a list of the updates available, and allow me to select which updates to install like...

[image]

It only seems to want to inform me when it wants to install updates, not the actual updates its installing.

Almost every time I install updates, after a few hours it wants to install more, yet when I view the update history, it tells me the last update installed was KB890830 on the 11th January 2017. I've run windows updates probably about 10-20 times since 11th Jan 2017.

So in summary it's repeatedly asking me to install updates, I don't know what its trying to install, none of what its installing gets listed in the update history, and there's nothing apparent to indicate there were any issues with the installation.

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: Why is your screenshot not from Windows 10?  You should download a 1607 ISO and install the feature update.  Doing so will repair and fix your the problem your current installation and allow you to install future updates.  Windows 10 doesn't allow you to select which updates are installed.  1703 will allow you to pause updates.  Windows 10 Professional allows you to defer feature updates for 6 months.  Windows 10 Home has neither feature this all updates are required

Comment: The word preceeding the screenshot is "like"... The question relates to finding an equivalent interface in Windows 10.  Rather than selecting updates, I'd settle for viewing what its going to install.  If I could see that its the same list of updates every time I go to run Windows Update, or see that they are actually different updates, I would have a clearer understanding of what's going on.

Comment: Windows 10 only lists which updates it's installing.  If you want more control use WSUS.  Although the client device still will only list what it will install, there is no UI like in the screenshot, on Windows 10

Comment: look at my answer in the duplicate link, here I postet a tool where you can see and select updates you want to install.