# Windows 10 1607 upgrade issues

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade, sql-server

Sorry there's a lot of issues, they could be related so I will list them in one question.  The issues are:-

1. As posted previously [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1176472/windows-10-1511-windows-updates-view-available-updates) Windows Update is failing to install the anniversary update.
2. I've since turned off Windows Update, until I can resolve issue #1 and now I'm getting an error every 20 minutes or so that sqlservr.exe has stopped working.  I can see in the in the event viewer I have entries such as...

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {9A4948D9-13FC-4FAC-B60A-FBA6EE0FB11C}
>    and APPID 
>   {50E1C3FD-EC35-490E-9CCF-C68F9AE91919}
>    to the user NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE SID (S-1-5-19) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

3. As advised in the comments on my previous question, I've downloaded an ISO of Windows 10 Enterprise: -

> en_windows_10_enterprise_version_1607_updated_jan_2017_x64_dvd_9714415.iso

...and have attempted to upgrade install, which is (I shouldn't be surprised) also failing.   I've tried several times, off a hard disk, off a usb, I attempted to boot off the usb but it would not allow an upgrade.

The EFI partition is 500mb and has 187mb free.

I've read multiple drives could be an issue, my hard disk is partitioned into 3 partitions, deleting all except the windows partition isn't really an option, I would prefer a fresh install before doing that.

The C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log is as follows...

```
2017-02-21 11:12:45, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::GetOnlineServiceId: Failed to get update service collection. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:12:45, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Initialize: Failed to get online service ID. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:12:45, Error                 DU     DUStartup: Failed to initialize CDUSession on thread ID 0x1d40. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:12:45, Error                 SP     SPInitializeDU: DUStartup failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:12:45, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::GetClientDUPackages: DU initialization failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:12:45, Error                 MOUPG  DUSetup: Failed to execute DUSetup seach and download  [0x80070422]
2017-02-21 11:12:52, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::BiosSdbDataSource::ApplyDataSource (251):  Missing bios item(s).[gle=0x8007064a]
2017-02-21 11:12:52, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::WicaEngine::RunComponents (658):   RunDataSources Failed: [0x8007064a].[gle=0x8007064a]
2017-02-21 11:12:52, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::WicaFactory::DoWicaRun (355):   Failed to run engine: [0x8007064a].[gle=0x8007064a]
2017-02-21 11:12:52, Error                 CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupAppraiser::ScanInternal (271):   WicaRun failed: [0x8007064a].[gle=0x8007064a]
2017-02-21 11:13:15, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::GetOnlineServiceId: Failed to get update service collection. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:15, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Initialize: Failed to get online service ID. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:15, Error                 DU     DUStartup: Failed to initialize CDUSession on thread ID 0x1d40. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:15, Error                 SP     SPInitializeDU: DUStartup failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:13:15, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: DU initialization failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:13:15, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute critical search and download [0x80070422]
2017-02-21 11:13:21, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::GetOnlineServiceId: Failed to get update service collection. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:21, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Initialize: Failed to get online service ID. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:21, Error                 DU     DUStartup: Failed to initialize CDUSession on thread ID 0x1d40. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:21, Error                 SP     SPInitializeDU: DUStartup failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:13:21, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: DU initialization failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:13:21, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute GDR search and download [0x80070422]
2017-02-21 11:13:29, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::GetOnlineServiceId: Failed to get update service collection. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:29, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Initialize: Failed to get online service ID. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:29, Error                 DU     DUStartup: Failed to initialize CDUSession on thread ID 0x1d40. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:29, Error                 SP     SPInitializeDU: DUStartup failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:13:29, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: DU initialization failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:13:29, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute driver search and download [0x80070422]
2017-02-21 11:13:37, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::GetOnlineServiceId: Failed to get update service collection. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:37, Error                 DU     DU::CDUSession::Initialize: Failed to get online service ID. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:37, Error                 DU     DUStartup: Failed to initialize CDUSession on thread ID 0x1d40. hr = 0x80070422[gle=0x000003f0]
2017-02-21 11:13:37, Error                 SP     SPInitializeDU: DUStartup failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:13:37, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::DownloadDynamicUpdates: DU initialization failed. hr = 0x80070422
2017-02-21 11:13:37, Error                 MOUPG  DUImage: Failed to execute LangPack search and download [0x80070422]
2017-02-21 11:27:01, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLFDLauncher. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:01, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MsDtsServer120. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:01, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:01, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:01, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\omsapi.toniconline.com.au. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:01, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:02, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:02, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:02, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:02, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:10, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2017-02-21 11:27:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLFDLauncher. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MsDtsServer120. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\omsapi.toniconline.com.au. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:18, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:18, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:27:23, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: "id" attribute is mandatory. void __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::LoadSupportedComponent(class UnBCL::XmlNode
*,int,class Mig::CMXEMigrationXml *,class  Mig::CMXEXmlComponent *) 2017-02-21 11:28:04, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #233850# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type: 40972  (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 65006e002d00550053000000 }) [gle=0x80004005]
2017-02-21 11:29:04, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #1102957# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216 (0x00060000), status = [6]"(null)", value = { type:  40972 (0x0000a00c), bytes ( 12 (0x0000000c) ): 65006e002d00550053000000 }) [gle=0x80004005]
2017-02-21 11:29:15, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLFDLauncher. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:15, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MsDtsServer120. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:15, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:15, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:15, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\omsapi.toniconline.com.au. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:15, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:16, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:17, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:29:25, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class  Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *) 2017-02-21 11:32:21, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] Failed to get preferred homegroup with hr=0x80070490
2017-02-21 11:35:28, Error                        CSetupAutomation::Resurrect: File not found: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\automation.dat[gle=0x00000002]
2017-02-21 11:35:28, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectAutomation: Failed to resurrect automation: 0x80070002[gle=0x00000002]
2017-02-21 11:35:30, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLFDLauncher. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:30, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MsDtsServer120. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:30, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:30, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:30, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\omsapi.toniconline.com.au. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:31, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:31, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:31, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:31, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:31, Error      [0x0803b6] MIG    Can't retrieve group information for user IIS APPPOOL\.NET v2.0 Classic. NetUserGetLocalGroups failed 0x000008AD
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error                 IBSLIB OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize: Failed to backup BCD database from "I:\Boot\BCD" to "C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback\Boot\BCD".[gle=0x00000002]
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error      [0x064199] IBSLIB SetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint): threw exception.: class RollbackException: RollbackException: Error(2), CSystemVolumeSelectionCheckpoint: Failed to backup BCD database. void
__cdecl  OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters
*)[gle=0x00000002] 2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error      [0x06418a] IBSLIB RollbackSetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint): threw exception.: class RollbackException: RollbackException: Error(2), CSystemVolumeSelectionCheckpoint: Failed to backup BCD database. void
__cdecl OSRollbackService::CCheckpointImpressario::SetCheckpoint(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters *)
void __cdecl OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Finalize(const unsigned short *,struct OSRollbackService::ICheckpointParameters
*)[gle=0x00000002]
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error      [0x06414e] IBSLIB RollbackSetCheckpoint(WinPEBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint) failed. Disabling Rollback.[gle=0x00000002]
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error                 SP     Error setting OS Switch Rollback checkpoint[gle=0x00000002]
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error                 SP     Operation failed: Update Boot Code. Error: 0x80004005[gle=0x000000b7]
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Finalize reported failure![gle=0x000000b7]
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error                 MOUPG  MoSetupPlatform: Using action error code: [0x80004005][gle=0x000000b7]
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionFinalize::ExecuteSetupPlatformFinalize(1314): Result = 0x80004005[gle=0x000000b7]
2017-02-21 11:35:34, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionFinalize::ExecuteRoutine(479): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpActionImpl<class CDlpErrorImpl<class CDlpObjectInternalImpl<class CUnknownImpl<class IMoSetupDlpAction> > > >::Execute(441): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteAction(3243): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::ExecuteActions(3397): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 MOUPG  CDlpTask::Execute(1631): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2067): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteTask(2030): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteInstallMode(815): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupManager::ExecuteDownlevelMode(391): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:48, Error                 SP     CSetupPlatform::ResurrectNewSystem: Cannot resurrect new system.: Win32Exception: \\?\C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\NewSystem.dat: The system cannot find the file specified. [0x00000002] __cdecl  UnBCL::FileStream::FileStream(const class UnBCL::String *,enum UnBCL::FileMode,enum UnBCL::FileAccess,enum UnBCL::FileShare,unsigned long)[gle=0x00000002] 2017-02-21 11:35:50, Error                 MOUPG CSetupManager::Execute(236): Result = 0x80004005
2017-02-21 11:35:50, Error                 MOUPG  CSetupHost::Execute(372): Result = 0x80004005
```

**EDIT:** I have a single hard disk with 3 partitions, two for OS and one for data. I attempted to install a new Windows 10 install into my spare OS partition (which did contain another copy of Windows 10), after deleting and recreating the partition I got the following error...

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an MBR
>   partition table. On EFI system, Windows can only be installed to GPT
>   disks

So I think perhaps the problem is as a result of the machine originally having been setup using MBR which is no longer supported.  I'm guessing (after backing up everything) I'll need to attempt to convert the disk from MBR to GPT?  Or just wipe everything and start afresh.

Any recommendations on how to convert MBR to GPT? Or should I just give up and wipe the whole disk and reinstall everything.

**EDIT2**: I've resolved this issue I encountered in Edit 1 and I no longer think it is connected to the Windows 10 upgrade issues from V1511 to V1607.

By default when I booted off the USB it booted as UEFI and wouldn't allow me to install windows.  There was another option in the boot menu to boot off the usb without UEFI, choosing that option enabled me to successfully install a new installation on Windows 10 in the spare partition.  I've resolved to gradually re-install everything in the new 1607 Windows 10 OS installation and then retire the OS in the other partition (Windows 10 1511) that refuses to be updated.

**EDIT 3:** I've not found a solution to upgrading the old system, but I can verify that the newly installed OS on another partition on the same hard disk is able to install windows updates without issue.

Comment: The installations seems damaged. Have you tried sfc /scannow ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files

Comment: @BenjaminHastings it came back with "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations"... so probably not the issue

Comment: Okay, that's good. First things first. You mentioned the DCOM error APPID {50E1C3FD-EC35-490E-9CCF-C68F9AE91919}. That is Windows Update Client API (wuapihost). Would you like to fix this or is this a result of your turning off Windows Update?

Comment: @BenjaminHastings I won't need to fix issue #2 if I can fix #1 or #3.... I must say I think it extremely odd that disabling the Windows Update Service causes the SQL Server Service to crash regularly

Comment: From what I've seen all over this seems to be a corrupted BCD. I'd suggest to try to rebuild the BCD https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-rebuild-the-bcd-in-windows-2624508

Comment: Do you have the correct SQL server version (compatible with W10) ?

Comment: @Overmind I'm running SQL Server 2014 12.0.4487.0 Standard Edition (select serverproperty('EditionID') returns -1534726760).  FYI if I enable the Windows Update service, the SQL Server Service stops crashing and of course I'd prefer Windows Update to be running and actually working (as opposed to closing all my work, rebooting, then failing every day)

Comment: For clarification: What is your disk drive setup? UEFI/GPT like this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825686.aspx. Is drive i: the installation media?

Comment: @BenjaminHastings yea i think that might be the crux of the problem.  I'll Edit my question to add new information.

Comment: @BenjaminHastings the short answer is that the disk is MBR, a single disk with 3 partitions